# How to restrict accessing resource from a service account in GCP

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I have created two service accounts `ServiceAccount1` and `ServiceAccount2`. `ServiceAccount1` should only access `Dataset1` and `ServiceAccount2` should not access it.

How can I stop accessing `Dataset1` from `ServiceAccount2`?

Answer (score 1):

In Web UI you can invoke `Share Dataset` Dialog
From there you can fine tune which account has what access
Read more in [Access Control](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/access-control)

Answer (score 0):

There's Cloud Identity & Access Management (IAM) feature where you can protect different cloud resources but looking at their current list of resources [0], it doesn't look like BigQuery datasets are supported yet.

[0] https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#curated_roles

Comment: There's a feature in BigQuery that predates IAM: Each dataset can define who can view and/or edit it - so no IAM is necessary for this.